# What is the correct layout to detect Aruba Beacon with AltBeacon's Android Beacon Library?

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, aruba

According with the library, to detect proprietary beacons, I must add a line like below corresponding to my beacon type. I need to know the correct proper expression for "setBeaconLayout".

Example:
`beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser(). setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Aruba Beacon data sheet here: http://www.arubanetworks.com/assets/ds/DS_LocationServices.pdf, it appears that their beacons transmit the iBeacon format.

You can find that beacon layout along with others here:

https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com/